# In Safari browser Angular Nebular buttons are [disabled] even after checked "false". Any clues why this is happening? (Works on Chrome and Mozilla)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, browser, nebular

I use Angular Forms where I pass **!form.valid** to the [disabled] property.

This works fine in Chrome and Mozilla browsers, and the buttons become **enabled** once the page finishes loading.

However, in Safari browser it doesn't work.

*I hope somebody has any clues what goes wrong here?*

Comment: I am facing the same issue, were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Actually, the issue was something with date picker formatting. If the date picker has validation and your button is related to form being valid, check the formatting of Date picker.

Answer (score 0):

What I do when I have to use some of those kinds of attributes is to set null when is false. Example:

```
<button [disabled]="condition || null">Click</button>
```